# How to bulkify the apex class to avoid governing limits

Tags: apex, bulkification

I wrote a query in apex class which given below.

```
List<User> result = [select id,FirstName,LastName,UserName,Email,Contactid from user where Contactid != null];
```

From the above query, I wanna get contact and account values. To get those, i written the following code contains soql queries inside the for loop. And in which results to hit governing limits.

```
for(User us : result){
            Contact co = [select id,AccountId,Lastname,Firstname,Email from Contact where id =: us.Contactid];
            Account ac = [select id,Name,Phone from Account where id =: con.AccountId];
            listmw.add(new MultiWrapper(us, acc, con));
        }
```

Note: We can also get the contact values in another way( like `select id,LastName,Contact.id,Contact.Lastname,Contact.Email from user`). Where, the way of getting contact is not a major part.

How to bulkify the above code.
please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the relationship between User and Contact is 1 to 1, code something like this should work:

```
// Assumes 1 to 1 relationship between User and Contact
Map<Id, User> contactToUser = new Map<Id, User>();
for (User u : [
        select Id, FirstName, LastName, UserName, Email
        from User
        where ContactId != null
        limit 10000
        ]) {
    contactToUser.put(u.ContactId, u);
}

for (Contact c : [
        select Id, AccountId, Lastname, Firstname, Email,
                Account.Id, Account.Name, Account.Phone
        from Contact
        where Id in :contactToUser.keySet()
        ]) {
    listmw.add(new MultiWrapper(contactToUser.get(c.Id), c.Account, c));
}
```

This is using a Map to keep hold of the User information and using a relationship query to query Contact and Account at the same time and for all the required Contact Ids in a single query.